# My page wont redirect to url using a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a project, which needs to have a sample login page, using this it was working but now it is not opening the url in the If statement

```
function validate() {
    var usern = document.getElementById("userIn").value;
    var passw = document.getElementById("passIn").value;
    var position = -1;

    var usernArray = ["User1", "User2"];
    var passwArray = ["Pass1", "Pass2"];

    for (var i=0; i <usernArray.length; i++) {
        if ((usern == usernArray[i]) && (passw == passwArray[i])) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (position != -1) 
    {
        alert("Login Was Successful!, You are being redirected to the homepage");
        window.location.href = 'home.html';
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Invalid Username and/or Password! Please try again.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which case of the IF statement you enters?

Comment: The second one, the one using the position != -1

Comment: invalid username? ok can you tell me the values you have?

Comment: the usernames and passwords work, but when the correct user is put in the alert pops up and says successful but it will not go to 'home.html' it just refreshes the html file it is in

Comment: this is weird, try setting the location.href to your relative path maybe

Comment: In the console, it works, however when manually doing this it just refreshes the form.

Comment: can you add your html form to try at our end?

Comment: Won't let me post here. Here is the code https://pastebin.com/ZVp3vxXQ

Comment: FYI, you can use `.includes` and `.indexOf` instead of for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding to the button on your form the attribute: **type="button"**

```
<button type="button" onclick="validate()">Login</button>
```

and your code will work perfectly, but notice that you need to consider the form being submitted also (by pressing **Enter** button on keyboard). Maybe try changing your code to this:

```
<script>
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        var usern = document.getElementById("userIn").value;
        var passw = document.getElementById("passIn").value;
        var position = -1;

        var usernArray = ["User1", "User2"];
        var passwArray = ["Pass1", "Pass2"];

        for (var i=0; i <usernArray.length; i++) {
            if ((usern == usernArray[i]) && (passw == passwArray[i])) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (position != -1)
        {
            alert("Login Was Successful!, You are being redirected to the homepage");
            window.location.href = 'home.html';
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Invalid Username and/or Password! Please try again.")
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and set the type attribute to your button to **submit**

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this `window.location.href=/home.html` so it is relative to the current domain. Or you could try the window.location.replace instead of href.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, I noticed using console to do the replace method it does "C:/home.html" but when I try using Website/home.html it directs me to "C:/Website/Wesbite/home.html, not sure why

Comment: And the files are stored all in the same directory?

Comment: Yep, 100%, it was working fine, then after a while I tried again and no luck since. Here is the code https://pastebin.com/ZVp3vxXQ

Comment: you can remove the onclick event of the button an just change that line for the form to that. `<form onsubmit="validate()">` that should work. Then you can do  window.location.href="home.html". Hope that helps